# How can I create a swimming div

Tags: asp.net, css, devexpress

I want to create a div as Facebook's chat bar. I want to see that div however scroll the window up or down.  Do you have any sugesstions about this?

Note: I have Devexpress aspx tools licence.

Çağın

Comment: Çağın, please post a screenshot of this DIV here.  I am not sure what you are asking about :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use css:

```
position: fixed
```

simple as that

Answer (score 1):

Use the `position:fixed` style on your div. E.g.

```
<div class="swimming">Content</div>
```

Css:

```
.swimming { position:fixed; left:0px; top:0px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is with CSS `position:fixed;`.

However, be aware that IE6 doesn't support `position:fixed;`. This may not matter to you (the few remaining IE6 users are used to sites being broken by now).

More importantly, many mobile browsers don't support `position:fixed;` either. This is more of an issue for a modern site. The reason they don't support it is because an element that has a fixed position could cause major layout issues on a smaller screen. Most of them treat 'fixed' as 'absolute' so that it is still outside the page flow, but can be scrolled.

See here for more info: http://www.quirksmode.org/m/css.html - it's got a table which shows support for this feature (and others) in the various mobile browsers. (but note that the mobile market is changing rapidly and this table may not be bang up to date)

Answer (score 0):

I believe `postion: fixed` is the CSS style you want.

```
<div style="position: fixed; top: 10px; left: 20px; right: 20px; height: 50px">
    content
</div>
```